# How can I check an string length for 48 characters and if it's to long cut all characters that exceed

Tags: string, excel, vba

how can I check an string length for 48 characters and if it's to long cut all characters that exceed 48 characters? I want to do this on Sym.Description2 below in the code(in IF and ELSE).
So as example System.Description="Ihavetomanycharactersinthisstringiwanttocutthisnow" a 50 characters string. So as an result this should be the new string: Sym.Description2 = "Ihavetomanycharactersinthisstringiwanttocutthisn" which is exactly 48 characters. I want to do this in VBA.

```
 'Description(2) field
    If System.Description <> "" Then
        Sym.Description2 = System.Description
    Else
        Sym.Description2 = System.Name
    End If
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT(Sym.Description2,48)` just returns the first 48 characters and you can use it in VBA or in Excel directly.

Comment: Thanks :)! It works, should have found the function but anyway thanks again :D